# Unique binary patterns on a Cube

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, geometry, symmetry

Given a cube where each face can be individually colored either black or white, I know there should be $2^6$ ways to color the cube.

How can I tell which cubes are duplicates of another cube but with a different orientation?

How can I tell how many unique cubes are there?

Comment: Burnside's lemma solves questions of this form where symmetry is involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not so bad to count directly.

- There is only one all-white cube.
- There is only one cube that has a single black square (up to orientation).
- There are only two cubes that have two black squares (up to orientation). Either the black squares are on opposite faces or they are adjacent.
- The "hard" case: how many cubes have three black squares? Either they meet at a corner or two of the three are on opposite faces. So there are only two.
- Can you count how many have four black squares?
- Have five?
- Have six?

Comment: I would imagine that 4, 5, and 6 are essentially 2, 1 and 0 but with the opposite color.  So is the answer 10 unique cubes?

Comment: That's right. I didn't want to post something that laid out everything all the way. If the first bullet points make sense, then you can work out the last ones and then add it all up.